# shardTestFiles unexpected behaviour with chromeoptions setting of --user-dir-data

Tags: google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, protractor, selenium-chromedriver

I have the following settings in my config file.

```
specs : ['../specs/sample1.js', '../specs/sample2.js']

capabilities : {
        'browserName' : 'chrome',
        'chromeOptions' : {
            'args' : [ '--user-data-dir=C:/Chrome/User Data' ]
        },

        shardTestFiles: true,
        maxInstances: 2
    }
```

There is nothing special about the tests in the spec file, just prints out the title of the url in the console.

When I run the test two chrome windows are opened up. But only one 
(random choice) of the spec file tests are run. Once the tests in that spec file are completed both the browsers close at the same time. The second spec file is orphaned out and errors out after some time. Both the browser icons are overlapping each other. Check image below.

[image]

When I comment out the args in chromoptions containing the user-data-dir option, everything works perfectly. Two chrome windows are opened and the spec files are divided among the two browser windows and run all tests to completion. In this case the browser icons are separate.

[image]

I want to use the existing chrome profile with parallel option as it speeds up page loading and has default cookies setup.

What is the solution to get this to work?

On latest versions of protractor, chrome, webdrivers running on windows 8